# Number of subgroups of semidirect product of two elementary abelian subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, semidirect-product

It is well known that a subgroup of the semidirect product $H\rtimes K$ is not in general semidirect product of two subgroups $H'\le H$ and $K'\le K$ but always exist some subgroups of $H\rtimes K$ on the form  $H'\rtimes K'$.

**Definition:** A subgroup $G$ of $H\rtimes K$ is called split if $G\simeq (G\cap H)\rtimes (G\cap K)$.

**Question 1:**  Let $E=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}\rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{m}$ be the semidirect product of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}$ by $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{m}$. What is the number of split subgroups of order $p^{s}$ in $E$.

**Question 2:** Let $E=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}\rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{m}$ be the semidirect product of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}$ by $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{m}$. What is the number of elementary abelian subgroups of order $p^{s}$ in $E$.

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: Which semidirect product is it?

Comment: Essentially, for each subgroup of $K$, you want to count the number of subgroups of $H$ that is normalises. There is far from enough information to answer your question at the moment. Please add more information, and also show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental problem with your question. You seem to be under the impression that your groups $E$ are well-defined, but that is not so. For example, there are two semi-direct products of type $C_2^2 \rtimes C_2$. One is the trivial (i.e. direct) product $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ and the other is $D_8$, the dihedral group of order $8$.

Ok, so maybe you want to exclude direct products. Even then you still need to specify a non-trivial action for "the" semi-direct product to make sense. For example, if $p=2$, $n=4$ and $m=1$ there are (at least) two genuine semi-direct products of type $C_2^4 \rtimes C_2$. One is the wreath product $C_2^2 \wr C_2$ and the other is $C_2^2 \times D_8$. I am not completely sure, but I think $32$ is the smallest order where there are at least two genuine semi-direct products of the type you want.